# Abspielen vs. spielen

Tags: verb-choice

Wie kommt es, dass man `Video abspielen` anstatt von `Video spielen` sagt? Das Tätigkeitswort `abspielen` wird noch gängiger als `spielen`verwendet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spielen= to play.
ABspielen= to play BACK.

A video "plays back" something that has already been recorded. Hence the use of the term "abspielen" for a video.

That is in contrast to "spielen," which only means to play. E.g. Ich spiele am Klavier.

Comment: nice sum up of my answer, but you exclude "Ereignisse, die sich abspielen" in your answer.. it's not "play back" here!

Comment: @christian.s: I was talking about "Aufnahme," not "Ereignisse." Apparently there are now videos of "live" events, but I (aged 56) am not familiar with this.

Comment: Kannst Du Noten vom Blatt abspielen - am Klavier? :) Natürlich sind die Noten auch ein Recording, eine Aufzeichnung.

Answer (score 7):

Das Wort "abspielen" bezieht sich fast immer auf Aufnahmen (recordings) oder Ereignisse.

Das Wort "spielen" ist einerseits das "play", z.B. spielen mit Spielzeug, andererseits aber auch das "play" wie in "playing guitar".

Jetzt kann man recht eindeutig den Bezug herstellen:

> Der Gitarrist spielt die Gitarre.
>
> Man spielt die Aufnahme ab.

Genau den Gitarrensound, den er vorher gespielt hat, spielst Du erneut ab.

Answer (score 5):

Ein Versuch, die implizite Frage zu beantworten, woher das "spielen" in "abspielen" stammt:

Ich vermute, dass *"ein Video abspielen"* als Analogie zu *"Musik abspielen"* gebildet wurde. Letzteres wiederum könnte von *spielen* im Sinne von "Ich spiele ein Musikinstrument" abgeleitet sein.

Die Vorsilbe *ab-* soll wohl das "ablaufen lassen" mitklingen lassen.

---

Randbemerkung: Das Verb *abspielen* hat auch noch eine andere Bedeutung. Ein Musiker kann z. B. vom Notenblatt abspielen.

Answer (score 2):

Abspielen bedeutet "eine Aufnahme wiedergeben". Trotz der Ähnlichkeit hat das nichts mit spielen zu tun.

Comment: *Hat nichts damit zu tun* ist vielleicht etwas zu stark.

Answer (score 2):

Das Verb [spielen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spielen) bezeichnet oft das Vollziehen einer Tätigkeit aus reinem Zeitvertreib oder Selbstzweck. Das Wort besitzt eine ganze Reihe von Bedeutungen und Einsatzmöglichkeiten, es ist sehr vielseitig, jedoch trotz seiner Ähnlichkeit mit dem Verb [abspielen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abspielen) nicht zu verwechseln oder synonym zu verstehen.

[Abspielen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spielen) repräsentiert eher das Spielen bzw. Ablaufenlassen von etwas von Anfang bis Ende, dass etwas durch mehrmaliges (Ab)Spielen abgenutzt wird oder ein Ereignis, welches gerade stattfindet (etwas *spielt sich ab*).

Ich konnte dazu mehr nicht finden, doch anhand des Beispieles im Duden ("*vom [Noten]blatt spielen, ohne geübt zu haben*") kann man darauf schließen, dass man ein Video *abspielt*, weil die Formulierung im Bezug auf frühere, analoge Medien übernommen wurde. Beispiel: Von der Musik-CD wurde ein Titel abgespielt. Was wird abgespielt? Ein Titel. Von wo wird er abgespielt? Von der CD. *Etwas* wird von *etwas* abgespielt. Abgespielt bezieht sich auf das, *was* gespielt wird, nicht wovon.

Quelle: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/)